# why program launched udevd can not resolve name correctly?

Tags: c, linux, bash, embedded-linux, udev

I would like my garmin watch to do some auto update when plugging to my Ubuntu usb socket.
therefore, I have added 90-garmin-fenix-3hr.rules under /etc/udev/rules.d/, like the following

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/device_added.sh"
```

and calling a external program in device_added.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! /usr/local/bin/showip 2>&1
then
        echo "successfully update" 
else
        echo "fail to update" 
fi
```

the external program `showip` uses `getaddrinfo` to resolve name,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
  int status;
  char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];


  /* setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE)); */
  openlog ("usbhotplug", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID , 0);

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

  if ((status = getaddrinfo("www.google.com", NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    return 2;
  }
}
```

However, when this is triggered by a usb hotplug event, it ends up with the following error

```
Mar 18 00:33:17 surreywater usbhotplug[7197]: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

When this program run manually, it has no issues with name resolving.

isn't `root` the user id of proccess launch by udevd? Why it fails in `getaddrinfo`?

Comment: you need to include a tag for the programming language you are using (`c`?) . Then the readers that search specfically for `c` (or other) programming language questions will read yours. Good luck.

Comment: *Lots* of details can go into the behavior you're seeing -- if SELinux or a similar security layer is in effect, udev and processes it spawns may be disallowed from making network connections. Timing matters (if this is happening on early boot, networking may not just be up yet), systemd service definition-layer limitations matter (systemd itself can create a new namespace for a service without any network access), etc.

Comment: If you're using a particular embedded-Linux distribution or stack, I would almost start with a forum where you'll be communicating with people who know those tools -- they'll know which of the above limitations are likely in a near-stock environment, and know what questions to ask to know if you've taken your configuration *out* of stock.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, 
Thanks for the reply, it is Ubuntu 20.04. and it is not bootup time, so  can be the security layer or systemd service definition layer.

Comment: I strace added strace in device_added.sh and get the `Operation not permitted` in sendmmsg, which is expected. 
however, process's status of `CapEff` is `0000003fffffffff`, which means it has all the capabilities, that quite confuses me why it even get the permission error in the first place.

Comment: Capabilities are only a starting point. Look at whether udev is running with a restricted set of syscalls available. Look at whether SELinux is in use. Look at whether AppArmor is in use. Look at whether it's being run in a network namespace where the routing table is just a big deny rule. Someone who knew Ubuntu would know which of those are most likely off the top of their head, but I'm not that someone.